# Calculating roots of multiple polynomials in numpy without using a loop

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

I can use the `polyfit()` method with a 2D array as input, to calculate polynomials on multiple data sets in a fast manner. After getting these multiple polynomials, I want to calculate the roots of all of these polynomials, in a fast manner.

There is `numpy.roots()` method for finding the roots of a single polynomial but this method does not work with 2D inputs (meaning multiple polynomials). I am working with millions of polynomials, so I would like to avoid looping over all polynomials using a for loop, map or comprehension because it takes minutes in that case. I would prefer a vectoral numpy operation or series of vectoral operations.

An example code for inefficient calculation:

```
POLYNOMIAL_COUNT = 1000000

# Create a polynomial of second order with coefficients 2, 3 and 4
coefficients = np.array([[2,3,4]])

# Let's say we have the same polynomial multiple times, represented as a 2D array.
# In reality the polynomial coefficients will be different from each other,
# but they will be the same order.
coefficients = coefficients.repeat(POLYNOMIAL_COUNT, axis=0)

# Calculate roots of these same-order polynomials.
# Looping here takes too much time.
roots = []
for i in range(POLYNOMIAL_COUNT):
    roots.append(np.roots(coefficients[i]))
```

Is there a way to find the roots of multiple same-order polynomials using numpy, but without looping?

Comment: "Is there a way to find the roots of multiple polynomials using numpy, but without using a for loop?" -- probably not (though you could probably hide the loop in a `map` or comprehension). Seems too specialized. I doubt that the looping per se is the problem so much as the fact that you want to do something computationally expensive millions of times.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, actually the problem is not just for loop, but any solution that involves non-vectoral operation. I'll try to make the question more clear.

Comment: To make your question actually clear, provide an [mcve]. And please see [ask]

Comment: Numba *might* help. Probably won't though. Are the polynomials always second order?

Comment: If the polynomials are all of the same degree (or even if there is a small upper bound on their degrees) then you could experiment with e.g. directly implementing Newton's method with vectorized operations. The danger here is that any increase in speed might be offset by greater numerical inaccuracy (since naive implementations of root-finding algorithms are likely to be inferior to `np.roots`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the special case of polynomials up to the fourth order, you can solve in a vectorized manner. Anything higher than that does not have an analytical solution, so requires iterative optimization, which is fundamentally unlikely to be vectorizable since different rows may require a different number of iterations. As [@John Coleman suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67721899/calculating-roots-of-multiple-polynomials-in-numpy-without-using-a-loop?noredirect=1#comment119704316_67721899), you might be able to get away with using the same number of steps for each one, but will likely have to sacrifice accuracy to do so.

That being said, here is an example of how to vectorize the second order case:

```
d = coefficients[:, 1:-1]**2 - 4.0 * coefficients[:, ::2].prod(axis=1, keepdims=True)
roots = -0.5 * (coefficients[:, 1:-1] + [1, -1] * np.emath.sqrt(d)) / coefficients[:, :1]
```

If I got the order of the coefficients wrong, replace `coefficients[:, :1]` with `coefficients[:, -1:]` in the denominator of the last assignment. Using [`np.emath.sqrt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.emath.html) is nice because it will return a `complex128` result automatically when your discriminant `d` is negative anywhere, and normal `float64` result for all real roots.

You can implement a [third order solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) or a [fourth order solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation) in a similar manner.

Comment: Thank you, second order solution will cover most of our needs.

Comment: @CanolGökel. I ended up removing the third order because it had too many masks and checks that needed to be done. I may post a fix later after I've played with it. For the second order, you may want to check for something like `np.isclose(d, 0)` to find double roots.

Comment: Though using quadratic formula as-is is not always cool, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2007723/113703. So I, having the same problem as the asker but in a graphics context (inverting a bilinear map for fractal generation using OpenCV), will fall back to explicit loops.